# Typescript: capture/infer type with constraint without actually extending/widening

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function, `build`, that builds a `User` with the passed in params. I'd like to type the function such that it knows which params are passed in and takes them into account in the return value.

My first thought was to capture the type of `params` and use that in the return type:

```js
type User = { name: string; admin: boolean };

const build = <T extends User>(params: T): T => params
```

This works well, as I can now do:

```js
build({ name: 'Jan', admin: true });
// return type is: { name: string, admin: true } as desired (notice admin: true, not boolean)
```

But, capturing the type with the `<T extends User>` constraint seems to have an unintended consequence of also widening the type. The following is now allowed without error:

```js
build({ name: 'Jan', admin: true, foo: 'shouldnt be allowed' });
// return type is: { name: string, admin: true, foo: string }
```

If I go with a simpler approach where I don't capture the type and just return a `User`, I do get the desired/expected behavior where passing params that don't exist on `User` results in an error, but the function returns a `User` without the extra type information from the params:

```js
const build = (params: User): User => params

// Type error as desired: Object literal may only specify known 
// properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type 'User'
build({ name: 'Jan', admin: true, foo: 'sdf' })
```

What I'd like to know is if there is a way of capturing the type of `params` so that I can use it in the return type but without widening the type.

Comment: You requirement is not clear. Do you want it accept subtype of `User`? If yes, the first approach is correct. You need define the generic explicitly when call it. If no, the second approach is correct,

Comment: Terminology & semantics note: extra properties do not *widen* the type, they *narrow* it.  A type like `inferface A {a: string}` means "any object whatsoever as long as it has a `string`-valued property at key `a`".  That's how structural typing and interface extensibility works: with `interface B extends A {b: number}`, every `B` is also an `A`.  And `B` is *narrower* than `A`, since not every `A` is also a `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not implement [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), but you can create custom restrictions on the argument types. For example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAdgQwLYQBcUcwiAllgOYDcUOAJnpcQEYD27ANhDllAF8aAKGEBjdllJRWAV3JcGqKAB4AKlAgAPYBCwM4sBIgB8ACjA5E+OMQDWEEOwBmUDdt37DDp6-hIoAH43KGIsCAA3JABKYg0UEyhLazw4UQB6dKgJKWAoWWMARmJMXAJiUgpqOkZmLGIyWQg6AXFJaQKkQuU5BQYzUvwiKAByACk+EYAaeiYWKEaIGYFokWFMqABRACVtgHltttz84wAmHvlFAewh4nHJmdr5xZmtYkKVmiA)):

```js
type User = { name: string; admin: boolean };

const build = <T extends User>(
    params: keyof T extends keyof User ? T : never
): T => params

// const user1: { name: string; admin: true; }
const user1 = build({ name: 'Jan', admin: true, });

// ERROR
const user2 = build({ name: 'Jan', admin: true, x: 1});
```

With the same idea, a bit more verbose, but with nicer error handling:

```js
const build = <T extends User>(
    params: keyof T extends keyof User ? T : User
): Pick<T, keyof User> => params
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for my case. I went with the more verbose version for better error handling.